# ARCH and GARCH Models

Tags: time-series, garch, arch

I found excellent notes on ARCH and GARCH models [here](http://public.econ.duke.edu/~boller/Econ.350/talk_garch_11.pdf). On page 3 it is given that:

Standard time series models:

\begin{eqnarray*}
Y_{t} & = & E\left(Y_{t}|\Omega_{t-1}\right)+\epsilon_{t}\\
E\left(Y_{t}|\Omega_{t-1}\right) & = & \mu_{t}\left(\theta\right)\\
E\left(Y_{t}|\Omega_{t-1}\right) & = & E\left(\epsilon_{t}^{2}|\Omega_{t-1}\right)=\sigma^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

What does this $\Omega$ means here? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, $\Omega_{t-1}$ is all the information available up to time $t-1$. For example, it can be considered as the observed values of your time series i.e. $Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, ...,  Y_{t-1}$. If I want to be more precise, it is the [$\sigma$-algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#.CF.83-algebra_generated_by_a_family_of_sets) generated by all these random variables i.e. $\Omega_{t-1}=\sigma\{Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, ...,  Y_{t-1}\}$.